# Remove extra comma after string

Tags: php, csv

I have a lot of data in a CSV file. I wrote some code to extract only column 1 and put it in a txt file:

```
fwrite($file2, $data[0].',');
```

Now, this created a TXT file with all values separated by a comma.
However, after the last value was read there was an extra comma

I don't need this, because when I used `foreach($splitcontents as $x=> $y)` using a comma delimiter, it reads a garbage value at the end because of the extra comma.

How do I remove or avoid the comma at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead of misreimplementing it.

Comment: the problem in using FGETCSV was , all data was separated by a SEMICOLON in just ONE column ... i.e column 1 had  x;y;z;c  etc...

Comment: so i had to use an array and print only the first column, - hence the usage of   $data[0] ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assembling the CSV file yourself field-wise you could use [fputcsv()](http://php.net/fputcsv) which puts it into the right format:

```
while (...) {
    fputcsv($file2, array($data[0], $data[1], $data[22])  );
```

The second parameter must be an array. If you really only want one column, then leave out the rest.

Also for reading the files back in, check out `fgetcsv()`. This might simplify your foreach + $splitstring approach.

Comment: You won't get a matching answer without showing the whole program part that contains the logic error.

Comment: i ve already used fgetcsv  , all data was separated by a SEMICOLON in just ONE column ... i.e column 1 had x;y;z;c etc..

so i had to use an array and print only the first column, - hence the usage of ( $data[0] . ',' ) ... all I want is THIS comma to be removed at the end of the file !!

Comment: You were using fgetcsv wrong then. There is a parameter where you can change the delimiter from `,` comma to `;` semicolon easily. Again: don't rexplain your problem cryptically, we already know that you are doing something incorrectly. Just show your code. [*CLICK HERE TO EDIT YOUR QUESTION*](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5360320/edit)

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve the problem is to use `rtrim($data, ',')` on the data you load from the second file before splitting it. This will remove the trailing comma.

If you want to fix the file itself, you can do this:

```
ftruncate($file2, ftell($file2)-1);
```

You have to do this just before you call `fclose()`

Comment: but I only use explode and splitcontents... This would give me the data without the commas. But, at the last data, when I use explode ..

Comment: FOR EX:  1,2,3,4,    ---- Here, in the end, explode gives me 4 and a (garbage value)  .... I don't want the comma ONLY at the end of that file... ( The data in itself does not have a comma)

Comment: If `$data = '1,2,3,4,';` then `rtrim($data, ',')` gives you `1,2,3,4` - without the last comma. Just do it right before you call `explode()`

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer to show a way you can actually remove the last comma from the file.

Comment: Wow, Thanks Mark ! that was simple yet i didn't have the patience to search for it . you are the best...

Comment: Honestly, I'd never heard of the `ftruncate()` function either, but made speedy use of the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php